# Array not getting displayed in a new window as pdf. Using fpdf class

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdf, fpdf

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $_SESSION['arr1'] = $row;
        $_SESSION['arr2'][] = $_SESSION['arr1'];
        $_SESSION['data'][] = $row['awb_no'];
        $_SESSION['items'] = $_SESSION['data'];
   }
     echo"The new value has been scanned!</br>";
  echo "<hr>";
  echo "The tracking id's of the currently scanned items are given below<br><hr>";
  foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $x => $value)
   {
    echo "$value";
    echo "<br>";
        # code...
   }

echo "<br><hr>";
print_r($_SESSION['arr2']);
echo "<hr>";
print_r($_SESSION['items']);
echo "<a href='something.php'>download in pdf format</a>";
  }
}
else
{
    session_destroy();
}
?>
</body>
    </html>
```

The above code is a part of an entire php file. In a nutshell this php file contains an array that stores data in the following manner,

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [d_no] => 21312 [a_no] => 05153341 [order_id] => 9929633865300 [forms] => [extras] => [flag] => 2015-08-07 14:18:04.0000 ) )
```

I want the above array to be passed to another page which reads the array and displays it using fpdf class. The code for this page is as shown below,

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
 $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $db="greenmobiles";
    mysql_connect("$host","$user","$password") or die("Cannot Connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db") or die("Cannot select DB!");    
require_once( "fpdf/fpdf.php" );
$textColour = array( 0, 0, 0 );
$headerColour = array( 100, 100, 100 );
$tableHeaderTopTextColour = array( 255, 255, 255 );
$tableHeaderTopFillColour = array( 125, 152, 179 );
$tableHeaderTopProductTextColour = array( 0, 0, 0 );
$tableHeaderTopProductFillColour = array( 143, 173, 204 );
$tableHeaderLeftTextColour = array( 99, 42, 57 );
$tableHeaderLeftFillColour = array( 184, 207, 229 );
$tableBorderColour = array( 50, 50, 50 );
$tableRowFillColour = array( 213, 170, 170 );
$columnLabels = array( "Sl No.", "Tracking id", "Forms req", "Extras" );
$data = $_SESSION['arr2'][];

// End configuration


/**
  Create the title page
**/

$pdf = new FPDF( 'P', 'mm', 'A4' );
$pdf->SetTextColor( $textColour[0], $textColour[1], $textColour[2] );
$pdf->AddPage();


/**
  Create the table
**/

$pdf->SetDrawColor( $tableBorderColour[0], $tableBorderColour[1], $tableBorderColour[2] );
$pdf->Ln(15);

// Create the table header row
$pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 15 );
// Remaining header cells
$pdf->SetTextColor( $tableHeaderTopTextColour[0], $tableHeaderTopTextColour[1], $tableHeaderTopTextColour[2] );
$pdf->SetFillColor( $tableHeaderTopFillColour[0], $tableHeaderTopFillColour[1], $tableHeaderTopFillColour[2] );

for ( $i=0; $i<count($columnLabels); $i++ ) {
  $pdf->Cell( 36, 12, $columnLabels[$i], 1, 0, 'C', true );
}

$pdf->Ln( 12 );

// Create the table data rows

$fill = false;
$row = 0;

foreach ( $data as $dataRow ) {

  // Create the left header cell

  // Create the data cells
  $pdf->SetTextColor( $textColour[0], $textColour[1], $textColour[2] );
  $pdf->SetFillColor( $tableRowFillColour[0], $tableRowFillColour[1], $tableRowFillColour[2] );
  $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 15 );

  for ( $i=0; $i<count($columnLabels); $i++ ) {
    $pdf->Cell( 36, 12, ( '$' . number_format( $dataRow[$i] ) ), 1, 0, 'C', $fill );
  }

  $row++;
  $fill = !$fill;
  $pdf->Ln( 12 );
}



$pdf->Output( "report.pdf", "I" );
?>
```

I want the array entries that were passed to this page to be displayed in a tabular form in pdf so that it can be downloaded.

The following is the error I am encountering,

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\something.php on
>   line 71
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\something.php on
>   line 71
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\something.php on
>   line 71
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\something.php on
>   line 71
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\something.php on
>   line 71
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\something.php on
>   line 71
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\something.php on
>   line 71
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\something.php on
>   line 71 FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF
>   file

Comment: which is the line:71 in the code you have shown?

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because the array element does not exists. So validate like this.

```
 //check for existence
   if(isset($dataRow)) {
    $pdf->Cell( 36, 12, ( '$' . number_format( $dataRow['d_no'] ) ), 1, 0, 'C', $fill );
    $pdf->Cell(10);
    $pdf->Cell( 36, 12, ( '$' . number_format( $dataRow['a_no'] ) ), 1, 0, 'C', $fill );
    $pdf->Cell(10);
    $pdf->Cell( 36, 12, ( '$' . number_format( $dataRow['order_id'] ) ), 1, 0, 'C', $fill );
  ------
  .....
  .....
 ---------
 }
```

The last error is due to the previous list of notices. When that gets clear the FPDF output error will get clear.

Comment: Hey this worked but the contents of the array is not getting displayed in the pdf file.

Comment: Check the edited code. Because you are looping $datarow[$i], it will not have any value. grab the value like $datarow[$i][d_no], $datarow[$i][a_no],.. etc. Please position it according to the cell position.

Comment: you can also remove  "for ( $i=0; $i<count($columnLabels); $i++ ) {"

Comment: still not getting. I am only getting the output of the following code $columnLabels = array( "Sl No.", "Tracking id", "Forms req", "Extras" );  In the pdf only a table with these columns are obtained. the individual values are not obtained in the table

Comment: sorry change the $dataRow[d_no] to $dataRow['d_no'].